# Redirect OutputStream to a file

Tags: java, outputstream

I have to use a method to write a model, from an api.

`mode.write(OutputStream out);`

At the moment I am doing that to see my output on my `console`:

`model.write(System.out);`

However, I would like to specify a file path to write the output to a file.

Any recommendations how I could take this `OutputStream` and change it into a `FileOutputStream` to write it to a file?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model.write(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
```

This is for binary data. If text is wanted (as using System.out suggests), look whether there is a

```
model.write(Writer out);
```

Then use a Writer to convert java text (Unicode) to binary data (bytes) having some encoding.
You may also omit the encoding for the default platform encoding, i.e. for a computer local file.

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
model.write(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(file), encoding)));
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) **is** an `OutputStream`, so you can simply do

```
model.write(new FileOutputStream("filename"));
```

Note that you will have to add some exception handling (`FileOutputStream()` can throw a `FileNotFoundException`).